# Calculating cumulative minimum with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to calculate the "cumulative minimum" array--basically, the minimum value of an array up to each index such as:

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.array([5.,3.,4.,2.,1.,1.,2.,0.])
cumulative_min = np.zeros(nums.size, dtype=float)
for i,num in enumerate(nums):
    cumulative_min[i] = np.min(nums[0:i+1])
```

This works (it returns the correct array([ 5.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])
), but I'd like to avoid the for loop if I can.  I thought it might be faster to construct a 2-d array and use the np.amin() function, but I needed a loop for that as well.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For any 2-argument NumPy [universal function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html), its [`accumulate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) method is the cumulative version of that function. Thus, `numpy.minimum.accumulate` is what you're looking for:

```
>>> numpy.minimum.accumulate([5,4,6,10,3])
array([5, 4, 4, 4, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a matrix which lower triangle (`np.tril`) is filled with values of your array `nums` and your upper triangle (`np.triu`, with second parameter 1, so the diagonal stays free) is filled with the maximum of the array. (**EDIT**: instead of the maximum, the first element of the array is the better way. -> comments)

```
nums = np.array([5.,3.,4.,2.,1.,1.,2.,0.])
oneSquare = np.ones((nums.size, nums.size))

A = nums * np.tril(oneSquare)
B = np.triu(oneSquare, 1) * nums[0]
A, B
```

**Out:**

```
(array([[ 5.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  3.,  4.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  0.]]),
 array([[ 0.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]))
```

Now take the minimum of each row:

```
(A+B).min(axis=1)
```

**Out:**

```
array([ 5.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])
```

Comment: You could also use infinity for the values in the upper triangle, rather than `nums.max()`.

Comment: @Blckknght Tried it, did not work at first glance, so I took the maximum... I tried again and infinity would change the `0`-part of `B` to `NaN`

Comment: nice.  Didn't know about the triangle functions, very useful.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I didn't think of `0*inf` being an issue, but it is. You could use `nums[0]`, since that's always a potential minimum value already. And really, using `max` wasn't too bad (it only adds an O(N)` term onto an already `O(N^2)` algorithm.

Comment: @Blckknght `nums[0]` is a good idea... I am going to change that.. Thanks!